# SBS2011 Disabling SharePoint because of problems

Tags: sharepoint, windows-sbs, windows-sbs-2011

Anyone with any definite ways to disable Sharepoint on SBS2011?

I can find no specific 'How To' or instructions on the Microsoft site, only mentions of it on technet without much other information.

Examples:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/smallbusinessserver/thread/6c814a79-0e29-4f76-87e5-2345441a2fbc/

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/smallbusinessserver/thread/53f961fe-b311-4444-b2d5-b30d6539175b/

I have a remote SBS2011 running Exchange servicing 5 users (2 of them full time) with huge performance issues (only 12GB RAM). I have restricted the Exchange message store (which has made a difference) but would also like to disable SharePoint as none of it's features are used and it is causing errors. Along with the Backup not working!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems uninstalling SharePoint is a bad idea on SBS2011.

I've disabled it to fix alot of the Event Log errors, but also came across [a technet article](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-GB/smallbusinessserver/thread/94c5f178-f020-4d0f-ba7c-11c415d0d862?prof=required) which is a PSConfig command you have to run from the console to reset it after a SharePoint update (which breaks Windows Backup amongst many other things!).

In order to update the SharePoint databases, you must manually run the PSconfig utility. To run the utility:

1. Open an Administrative command prompt.
2. Change directory to `C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\BIN`.
3. Run `PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures`.

Answer (score 1):

Disabling Sharepoint isn't the answer because of it's integration with the server overall.

Instead, please follow the recommendations in these articles to limit memory use for Monitoring and Sharepoint:

http://www.thirdtier.net/2009/08/setting-the-maximum-memory-usage-on-sbsmonitoring/

http://www.thirdtier.net/2009/08/setting-the-maximum-memory-usage-on-the-sharepoint-database/

http://www.thirdtier.net/2012/01/solving-the-unresponsive-exchange-sbs-server-problem/